# ListView Inflation/Preservation

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I have a GridView of ImageButtons where the user can select an element to add to the ListView which is the following View.  The user will need to make multiple selections from the GridView.  This means they will have to navigate back and forth between the two Views, adding their selections to the ListView.  I need to know how to re-inflate the ListView with the elements that have already been chosen along with the new choice.  Basically, I am struggling with how to preserve the list contents and then inflate the contents when another selection is made.  I have been trying to use an ArrayAdapter, but I have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common to overlook the need to use notifyDataSetChanged() when getting to grips with ListView. Below is a basic rundown of how to populate and refresh a ListView.

Create an ArrayList for your list of elements, a ListView to display them in, and an ArrayAdapter to connect them:

```
private ArrayList<String> mMyElements;
private ListView mMyListView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mMyArrayAdapter;
```

Setup your ListView:

```
mMyListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
mMyListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);  // There are other ChoiceModes available,
                                                           // but I'm guessing this is the most likely one you want for your situation.
```

Setup your ArrayAddapter and assign it to the ListView:

```
mMyArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, mMyElements);
mMyListView.setAdapter(mMyArrayAdapter);
```

Now you can change what is displayed in the ListView, by changing what is contained in your ArrayList. Use notifyDataSetChanged() to signal to the ArrayAdapter that it needs to update the display of the ListView:

```
...
// Code which changes the elements contained in the ArrayList
// For example..
myElements.add(x);
myElements.remove(y);
...
// Notify the ArrayAdapter that it's ArrayList has changed.
mMyArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // This line is vital to get the altered ArrayList to display.
mMyListView.clearChoices();  // You may want to clear any old selections from the ListView when you refresh the display.
```

**`<Additional>`**
If by "re-inflate" you mean that your GridView and ListView are in different Activites or Fragments, all you need to do is maintain the ArrayList `myElements` when navigating between them. You can pass the ArrayList between them in an intent.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, by re-inflate I meant that they were in different Fragments and I was losing my list contents at each new instance.

Comment: So did passing the list between the fragments using an intent solve your problem? If so, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: yeah, i was so happy to be able to move forward with my app that i forgot.  thanks again.